# How to override rails-projections for lib in vim-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim

my structure is like that:

```
lib/managing_bookmarks/create.rb
spec/use_cases/managing_bookmarks/create_spec.rb
```

I would like to add or override custom rails-projection behaviour like here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/extending-rails-vim-with-custom-commands

I added to my .vimrc

```
let g:rails_projections =  {
  \   "lib/**/*.rb": {
  \     "command": "lib",
  \     "test": "spec/use_cases/%s_spec.rb",
  \     "related": "spec/use_cases/%s_spec.rb",
  \   }
  \ }
```

But it doesn't work as expected. How to do that?

Comment: It may be worth opening a [ticket](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/issues). Looks like you have: [How to override rails-projections for lib in vim-rails?](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/issues/422)

Answer (score 0):

Tim answered me here on github: https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/issues/422#issuecomment-120083611